# Embedded DBMS with XML support for .NET?

Tags: .net, xml, database, nosql, embedded-database

Is there an .NET-enabled embedded database (like SQLite.NET) with support for XML?

It doesn't matter for me if it is SQL or NoSQL, XPath, document-oriented or not.

I just know of BerkeleyDB XML, but this project is still alha and seem to be dead for a year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is no alternative to berkeley db.

Comment: It has C++ API (not C) so it's problematic to use it in .NET :(

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd add an answer in case anyone stumbles on it. My company just released an open source embedded XML database for the .NET platform called Nxdb. It's under the Apache 2.0 license and has been in development and use internally for several years. It's basically a binding to a cross-compiled (using [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/)) version of [BaseX](http://basex.org/) (a fantastic Java XML database) along with extra functionality for the embedded use case and the .NET environment. The project page is here: https://dracorp.assembla.com/spaces/nxdb

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem with SQL Server Compact Edition?

Comment: Yes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact: "The current release does not support stored procedures or native XML data type either"

Answer (score 0):

How about [VistaDB.Net](http://www.vistadb.net/)? See comparison with SQL Server CE [here](http://www.vistadb.net/compare/sql-ce.aspx).

Comment: I cannot find any information that says VistaDB.Net supports XML in any way.